# Query inside Dynamic triggers continuous high CPU load for FE

Tags: front-end, dynamic, query, hardware

Here is a (vicious) problem I am able to reproduce with v12 and v11.3 (previous versions not tested) and OSX.

This is a minimal example to demonstrate it (even if it seems useless here I do need `Dynamic` to display results in real time in some more complicated code) and which triggers for me a continuous max cpu load :

```
DynamicModule[{searchstring = "tr"},
 (* InputField[Dynamic[searchstring, ...]]*)
 {<|"aa" -> 1, 
     "bb" -> 1|>, <|"aa" -> 2, "bb" -> 2|>} // 
   Query[Select[#"aa" < 2.*StringLength@searchstring &]] // Dynamic
 ]
```

while the following don't trigger it :

(Here i get rid of `Query` and use the operator form of `Select`):

```
DynamicModule[{searchstring = "tr"},
 (* InputField[Dynamic[searchstring, ...]]*)
 {<|"aa" -> 1, 
     "bb" -> 1|>, <|"aa" -> 2, "bb" -> 2|>} // 
   Select[#"aa" < 2.*StringLength@searchstring &] // Dynamic
 ]
```

or

(here i just get rid of the constant `2.` which multiplies `StringLength` !)

```
DynamicModule[{searchstring = "tr"},
 (* InputField[Dynamic[searchstring, ...]]*)
 {<|"aa" -> 1, 
     "bb" -> 1|>, <|"aa" -> 2, "bb" -> 2|>} // 
   Query[Select[#"aa" < StringLength@searchstring &]] // Dynamic
 ]
```

Do you observe the same ? Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: I observed the same think on Windows 10 / Mathematica 12. I confirmed with LinkSnooper that your first command creates a constant communication between the front end and the kernel. Also, when I removed the multiplication, the problem does not happen. I don't know why it happens, but it looks like it is the Kernel that is constantly telling the FrontEnd to refresh.

Comment: Actually it looks like the problem appears as soon as you do any arithmetics (+-*/^) with the dynamic variable : `DynamicModule[{number = 12},
 {<|"aa" -> 1, "bb" -> 1|>, <|"aa" -> 2, "bb" -> 2|>} // 
   Query[Select[#"aa" < number^2 &]] // Dynamic
 ]`

Comment: p.s. I'd report it to WRI Support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick fix is to add `TrackedSymbols :> {searchstring}` to the `Dynamic`.

But at the end it is just another example from a neverending series "Dynamic does/not fire unexpectedly".

This series taught me to not use `Dynamic` to calculate things but only to display them. It will be more work on your side but it will dramatically reduce number of headaches.

This is how more or less I do things lately:

```
DynamicModule[
  {searchstring, viewResults, searchstringSet}
, {
    InputField[Dynamic[searchstring,searchstringSet[#]&], String, ContinuousAction->True]
  , Dynamic[viewResults]
  }
, Initialization:>(
    searchstringSet[val_]:=(
      searchstring=val
    ; viewResults = {<|"aa"->1,"bb"->1|>,<|"aa"->2,"bb"->2|>} // Query[Select[#"aa"<2.*StringLength@searchstring&]]
    )
  ; searchstringSet["tr"]
  )
]
```

Comment: On my computer, under Version 12, your code produces no useful result, i.e., an InputBox with tr in it, which if evaluated reproduces the two Associations with the strings "aa" and "bb".  You write that TrackedSymbols is necessary, but it is not in your code.  What is this code meant to accomplish, and how does one make it do it?

Comment: @CElliott works for me v12 Win10. It is meant to do what OP meant it to do, it shows all of associations where `aa` is greater than the string length of your input. So if you enter e.g. `t` only the first one should be shown.
I didn't say TrackedSymbols is necessary, it was a quick fix for OP's code. But I went with a general solution, not a quick fix. Let me know if something still isn't clear.

Answer (score 6):

You may use the [`TrackedSymbols`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackedSymbols.html) option on either `DynamicModule` or `Dynamic`.

From the comments in the OP the front-end cannot determine when to refresh the dynamic with the usage of the dynamic variable in `Query`.  You can explicitly tell the front-end which variable to track for updates with `TrackedSymbols`.

```
DynamicModule[{searchstring = "tr"},
 Dynamic[
  {<|"aa" -> 1, "bb" -> 1|>, <|"aa" -> 2, "bb" -> 2|>} // 
   Query[Select[#"aa" < 2.*StringLength@searchstring &]],
  TrackedSymbols :> {searchstring}]
 ]
```

Now that the symbols to track have been explicitly provided, the front-end will only refresh the `Dynamic` when that symbol changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which is the simplest for sure. However I decided to accept Kuba's answer to highlight the problems with dynamics and the valuable answer.

Comment: By the way, is there a reason `TrackedSymbols` is not an official option for [`DynamicModule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html). Given the many problems with the updating, it really should ...

Comment: @SquareOne There is nothing `Dynamic[]` about `DynamicModule`, so to speak: It does no tracking at all and generates no updating.  Only symbols in `Dynamic[]` wrapped code are tracked.  `TrackedSymbols` only makes sense inside a `Dynamic[]`, whether it is one wrapped automatically around the body of a `Manipulate[]` or, as per the docs, required outside `Refresh[]` for `Refresh` to work properly.

Comment: @MichaelE2 ;) I've just started to use `DynamicModule` instead of `Manipulate` and thought that `TrackedSymbols` would also be an option of that function ! I did not even notice that in the solution given, the option was part of `Dynamic`. Shame.

Comment: @MichaelE2 and I see that Edmund just wrote in his answer that `TrackedSymbols` is a `DynamicModule` option also ;)

Comment: @SquareOne Yes, I noticed that, too. I also tested it. ;)  I also executed `Options@DynamicModule`.  Any idea what `TrackedSymbols` does to `DynamicModule`? (I don't. It does not generate an error, though.) I think the reference to using it in `DynamicModule` should be removed from the answer.  I already upvoted this answer, but the answer would be more accurate without it.